# Decrease div on animation from two points in a loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want that when I click on the blank circle the div will decrease and increase into the other point and so on...
As for now the div just disappear as for the 0 scale.

Here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/492/#&togetherjs=kjsiV35jyD

Here is the css:

```
#bg {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  width:300px;
  height:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
}

#target_a{
    position:absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
   border-radius:50%;

  top:-15px;
  left:250px;
}

#target_b {
    position:absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
   border-radius:50%;

  top:-15px;
  left:50px;
}

#circle {

  position:relative;
  left:96px;
  top:30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color:#feb009;

     -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);  
}

#circle.clicked {

    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the use of the pseudo-element `:after` instead of the `#circle` div you have.

Check this:

```js
$('#bg').on('click','div', function() {
  $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
#bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
#target_a {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -15px;
  left: 250px;
}
#target_b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50px;
}

#bg > div:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:80%;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:80%;
  margin:10%;
  background:yellow;
  transform:scale(0);
  transform-origin:center;
  transition:all .3s linear;
}
#bg > div.clicked:after {
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg">
  <div id="target_a" class="clicked"></div>
  <div id="target_b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the effect you are after using CSS animations and keyframing.  That is, if I understand what you are asking.  I left most of your CSS "as is", but my intuition tells me it can probably be simplified.

```js
$('#target_a').on('click', function() {
  $('#circle').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
@keyframes boing {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(0); }
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#bg div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -15px;
}

#target_a { left: 250px; }
#target_b { left: 50px; }

#circle {
  position: relative;
  left: 96px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #feb009;
  transition: all .5s;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#circle.clicked {
  animation-name: boing;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg">
  <div id="target_a"></div>
  <div id="target_b"></div>
</div>
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Reading your question and the @DaniP answer again, I think what they suggested is the effect you are after.  I will leave this for now, but let me know if this was not the effect you were looking for.